# Make TinyMCE Work Properly with JEditable

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tinymce, jeditable

I'm using the Edit-in-Place JQuery plugin, JEditable: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable.

I would like to use TinyMCE when editing, so I found some extra script to make it work: http://sam.curren.ws/index.cfm/2008/6/12/jEditable-TinyMCE-Plugin.

The problem I'm having is that, either JEditable or TinyMCE crashes the first time I try to edit something -- but it works perfectly afterwards! Specifically, when I first click the area to edit, TinyMCE loads, but when I clicked on the textarea, the textarea vanishes and becomes the div I was about to edit (as if I never clicked to edit). However, afterwards, the plugin works perfectly unless I refresh the page.

CODE

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script> <!-- TinyMCE -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script> <!-- JQuery-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/jquery.jeditable.mini.js"></script><!-- JEditable plugin-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/jquery.tinymcehelper.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/jquery.company.js"></script>
<div class="editable_textarea">Edit this div</div>
```

What's happening is that when I click on the text "Edit this div", TinyMCE loads. But then when I click on the textarea, the  textarea vanishes and I just see the text "Edit this div" (as if I didn't click to edit-in-place). **I only have this problem when I load/refresh the page. Afterwards, everything works perfectly.**

This is my code for jscripts/jquery.tinymcehelper.js (exactly the same as in http://sam.curren.ws/index.cfm/2008/6/12/jEditable-TinyMCE-Plugin):

```
$.fn.tinymce = function(options){
   return this.each(function(){
      tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, this.id);
   });
}

function initMCE(){
   tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textarea",
        theme: "advanced",
        height: "100",
        plugins: "table, tinyautosave, imagemanager, spellchecker, autoresize",
        theme_advanced_buttons1_add_before : "tinyautosave, code, separator, delete_table",
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,fontsizeselect,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,code,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,insertimage,spellchecker",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left"
    });
}

initMCE();

$.editable.addInputType('mce', {
   element : function(settings, original) {
        var textarea = $('<textarea id="'+$(original).attr("id")+'_mce"/>');
        if (settings.rows) {
           textarea.attr('rows', settings.rows);
        } else {
           textarea.height(settings.height);
        }
        if (settings.cols) {
           textarea.attr('cols', settings.cols);
        } else {
           textarea.width(settings.width);
        }
        $(this).append(textarea);
           return(textarea);
        },
        plugin : function(settings, original) {
           tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, $(original).attr("id")+'_mce');
           },
        submit : function(settings, original) {
           tinyMCE.triggerSave();
           tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", true, $(original).attr("id")+'_mce');
           },
        reset : function(settings, original) {
           tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", true, $(original).attr("id")+'_mce');
           original.reset();
   }
});
```

Finally, this is my "customization" code:

```
// Jeditable customization
$(function(){
       $(".editable_textarea").editable('ajax/save.php?editnotetext',
        {
          type : 'mce',
          indicator : 'Saving...',
          tooltip : 'Click to edit...',
          name : 'note_text',
          submit : 'OK',
          cancel : 'Cancel',
          height : '100px'
       });
      $(".dblclick").editable('ajax/save.php?editnotename', { 
        tooltip   : 'Doubleclick to edit...',
        indicator : 'Saving...',
        event   : 'dblclick',
        name : 'name',
        style   : 'inherit'
      });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing I noticed is that your `initMCE()` method isn't exactly the same as in the link (I couldn't get to the site, but was able to pull it up from Google cache). Specifically, the `mode` should be `none`.

Looking at the TinyMCE docs, it would seem that `mode: 'textarea'` is meant for auto attaching to `<textarea>` elements.  Whereas, `mode: 'none'` is meant for programatically adding the editor to a field, which is what the JEditable plugin is trying to do.

Comment: Also, if the TinyMCE textarea vanishes, I'm suspecting that clicking on it is blurring focus and JEditable is cancelling the edit (which is the default).  To counteract this, add the parameter `onblur: 'ignore'` to the JEditable configuration.

Comment: hey plecong. i had the initial config for tinymce as described in the website and had the same problem. 

I will check out onblur though and get back. thanks!

Comment: Adding the parameter `onblur: 'ignore'` worked! Thanks for your help!

Comment: No prob.  I found your post as I was also trying to use TinyMCE with Jeditable.  I ended up abandoning it for cleditor instead because I didn't need that much functionality.

Answer (score 1):

So one "solution" I found is to use IPWEditor instead (http://spacebug.com/projects/ipweditor_in-place_wysiwyg_editor/).

It doesn't seem to have as much functionality as JEditable. It uses Editable but may support JEditable in future.

If anyone manages to solve the problem with JEditable or has a better plugin, please let me know.